# While loop break/continue not working for me

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

I can't see why my loop won't continue when the input is not a float!
The addition is clearly the issue, but I don't understand why python tries addition when any non float input should terminate the loop in the exception.

**Code:**

```
tot1 = 0.0       
count1 = 0.0    
while(True):
    inp1 = input('Enter a number or done to end:')
    try:
        float(inp1)
    except:
        str(inp1)
        if(inp1 == 'done'):
            print("done!")
            break
        print("Error")
        continue    
    tot1 = tot1+inp1
    count1 = count1+1

if(tot1 >0 and count1 >0):
    print("Average: ", tot/count )
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/GregerAAR/PycharmProjects/untitled/chap5exc.py", line 16, in <module>
    tot1 = tot1+inp1
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Read this please — http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Sergey, any specifics that I can improve in my questions? 
Any feedback would be appreciated :)

Comment: Now I think it's OK. I meant formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are never assigning `inp1` to the float you return from `float(inp1)`.

You need to reassign `inp1 = float(inp1)`. This isn't a loop/break issue, it's you not properly assigning variables. `float(inp1)` returns the floating point number of `inp1`, which you then never assign to anything.

In summary, `inp1` is still a string from `raw_input`, which is why you get the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

check for `'done'` first then cast to float with `inp1 = float(inp1)`, you don't need to call `str(inp1)` as it is already a string, furthermore it actually does nothing as you don't assign it to any variable  anyway.

```
tot1 = 0.0
count1 = 0.0
while True:
    inp1 = input('Enter a number or done to end:')
    if inp1 == 'done':
        print("done!")
        break
    try:
        inp1 = float(inp1) # cast and actually reassign inp1
    except ValueError: # catch specific errors
        print("error")
        continue
    tot1 += inp1
    count1 += 1


if tot1 > 0 and count1 > 0:
    print("Average: ", tot1 / count1 ) # tot1/count1 not tot/count
```